# CakePHP urls with unique ids

Tags: php, cakephp

I have seen urls such as this on some CakePHP websites: `http://sample.com/posts/WordPress_get_URL_based_on_page_post_name-O8C`

What would the `08C` part be? As on my current setup I pass the title and id to the url to give each item a nice url e.g. `http://driz.co.uk/cake/portfolio/view/NA_Software-4` but my id is just a number. How would I change it to get a 3 character id that mixed numbers and letters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess the tiny number is just a short slug.

If you already use integers for your records I don't see a point of adding an additional overhead to create tiny slugs. Also the tiny slug won't have always 3 characters when you get a decent amount of records. Tiny slugs make the most sense if you need a short URL like in emails or for twitter and other similar usecases.

However if you want to use them the CakeDC Utils plugin comes with a TinySluggable behavior.
https://github.com/CakeDC/utils